# Docker on Windows Server 2016 (1803) can't build same dockerfile on Windows 10

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am trying to create a Windows Docker image built off the `microsoft/wcf` image. The WCF service relies on a COM component that is installed and registered from an MSI from a 3rd party.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/wcf

WORKDIR C:/local

COPY SomeInstaller.exe ./

RUN ./SomeInstaller.exe /SP /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOICONS

WORKDIR "C:/Program Files/SomeProgram/Interface"

RUN regsvr32 SomeProgramCOM.dll /s

WORKDIR C:/certs
COPY ./ops-certs .

RUN powershell "./Install-OpsCertificates.ps1"
```

When I build this on my local Windows 10 environment, it works correctly. The installer finishes successfully, the files are located in the right location, and the COM registration passes. However, when I run this on our build server (Windows Server 2016 1803 update) the installer does not work (fails silently) and the COM dll is not being registered.

Shouldn't the output be the exact same when building this Dockerfile?

Build output

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for microsoft/wcf:latest
 ---> e4b543a82489
Step 2/9 : WORKDIR C:/local
Removing intermediate container cf6b7d21b207
 ---> 5e943a9bd1be
Step 3/9 : COPY SomeProgram.exe ./
 ---> c1e0781fb180
Step 4/9 : RUN ./SomeProgram.exe /SP /VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NOICONS
 ---> Running in 2cc2bb26cea4
Removing intermediate container 2cc2bb26cea4
 ---> 1ed4cbf280ad
Step 5/9 : WORKDIR "C:/Program Files/SomeProgram/Interface"
Removing intermediate container 9c5df9cc4cfd
 ---> 5387093d3311
Step 6/9 : RUN regsvr32 SomeProgramCOM.dll /s
 ---> Running in 66ddc85117fc
Removing intermediate container 66ddc85117fc
 ---> 453a43979c71
Step 7/9 : WORKDIR C:/certs
Removing intermediate container 03fefdeb069b
 ---> a42989c178fb
Step 8/9 : COPY ./ops-certs .
 ---> 4d60c35a7bab
Step 9/9 : RUN powershell "./Install-OpsCertificates.ps1"
 ---> Running in 8cecda9be47c
Scrip execution directory is C:\certs
Installing Certificates . . .


   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\Root

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
8C048578CA1E43CB577C2A64C3AD3101C64FAFC3  CN=MyCompany Root Certificate...
8C048578CA1E43CB577C2A64C3AD3101C64FAFC3  CN=MyCompany Root Certificate...
Import of Root certificate to Root Store Succeeded!!!!!!


   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\CA

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
8C048578CA1E43CB577C2A64C3AD3101C64FAFC3  CN=MyCompany Root Certificate...


   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\Root

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
8C048578CA1E43CB577C2A64C3AD3101C64FAFC3  CN=MyCompany Root Certificate...
Import of Root certificate to CA Store Succeeded!!!!!!


   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\CA

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
22A3E8B4AEC702987A2CBAEDD42573ED97E5BB53  CN=MyCompany Secure Certifica...
22A3E8B4AEC702987A2CBAEDD42573ED97E5BB53  CN=MyCompany Secure Certifica...
Import of Intermediate certificate to CA Store Succeeded!!!!!!


Removing intermediate container 8cecda9be47c
 ---> 73b2682580ce
Successfully built 73b2682580ce
Successfully tagged local/someprogram:latest
```

Also, note that I did run the installer for SomeProgram on the windows server and it worked properly, so there should be no compatibility issues.

Comment: Paste output of build process

Comment: So how do you know if registry modification was not successfull? Did you verify registry entries? Also try to specify explicitely base images and see if it makes a difference. `4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803`

Comment: explicitly defining the base image didn't help. I did check the docker versions and on the server is Docker EE 18.03 and on my local machine it is Docker for Windows 18.06.1. that is the only difference I can find between the two environments